# How to know if php file is being called within a src="..."?

Tags: javascript, php, src

In my website I have

```
<script src="js.php"></script>
```

Question is very simple but I have no idea of the answer:

Within js.php, how can I check if the file has been called though a script src="..."?

Purpose is to change the returned HTML code of js.php depending on how this php script file is called (direct access or script src="...").

Comment: Is this supposed to be some feigned security feature? Because that's not going to work. You can differentiate between HTTP ("direct") requests, and PHP includes from a different invocation script. But there's no reliable way to figure out the HTML link origin or discern between include/require/_once etc.

Comment: Yes this is related to security. This must be resilient to user hacks for instance <script src="js.php?callMethod=src"></script> is not a solution as anyone could direct access to http://.../js.php?callMethod=src in the browser navigation bar and fool the system making it believes that we are calling through a script src="..." inclusion.

Comment: Anyone who wanted to could read the script out of the browser's cache anyway.

Answer (score 2):

The way to do it would be to assign a session variable to true right before you call the js.php file

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['src'] = true;
<script src="js.php"></script>
```

Then in the php file

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['src']) && $_SESSION['src'] == true) {
    // file was called from a src
    $_SESSION['src'] = false; // this is important so that it can't be called from direct access
}
```

Comment: The `===` comparison shouldn't be used habitually. It's not going to work here, because `true` is going to be a string. Use `"true"`.

Comment: Right, @mario my bad.

Comment: This is not fulfilling the requirement: anyone could direct access to http://.../js.php?src=true in the browser navigation bar and fool the system making it believes that we are calling through a script src="..." inclusion.

Comment: @user2824618 I thought of another way, let me edit my answer.

Comment: what about checking `get_included_files()`?

Comment: @Ali Thanks. This is a very good and clever way to do it if you can put PHP code in the webpage calling the js.php file. However in my particular case, the webpage supposed to call the js.php script within a script src="js.php" is not handling php.

Answer (score 2):

Cool question. Let me help ya.

I'll provide here some not 100%-reliable methods, that will work in standard, non-user-malicious cases.

## First

For this solution you will be required to download mimeparser from [here](https://code.google.com/p/mimeparse/downloads/detail?name=mimeparse-php-0.1.2.tar.gz&can=2). It's your choice what kind of mimeparser you want to use, I found this just ad-hoc for purpose of this answer.

## Theory

In theory browser is sending headers, that your script during response should match for proper browser-side parsing. Especially I have here in mind `HTTP_ACCEPT` header.

## Code example

Once you have downloaded mimeparser, lets start with creating file `test.php`:

```
<?php // test.php

//https://code.google.com/p/mimeparse/
include_once('mimeparse.php');

$mimeMatch = Mimeparse::best_match(array('text/javascript', 'text/css', 'text/html', 'application/xhtml+xml', 'application/xml', 'image/*'), $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT']);

switch($mimeMatch) {
    case 'text/javascript': // via <script src>
        echo('alert("this is loaded as script");');
        break;
    case 'image/*': // via <image src>
        header('Location: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sOq8x.jpg?s=128&g=1');
        break;
    case 'text/css': // via <link href>
        echo('body::before{content: "this is written via CSS"}');
        break;

    default:

        var_dump('detected standard file request by matching to ' . $mimeMatch);

        // if __FILE__ is first on a list, its not included
        if(__FILE__ !== array_shift(get_included_files())) {
            var_dump('file was included or required');
        } else {
            var_dump('file runs on its own');
        }

        // additional detect for ajax request.
        if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
            var_dump('loaded via AJAX request');
        } else {
            var_dump('loaded via not-AJAX request');
        }

        break;
}
die();
```

You can visit it by now, to see that script detects, its loaded directly:

```
string 'detected standard file request by matching to text/html' (length=55)
string 'file runs on its own' (length=20)
string 'loaded via not-AJAX request' (length=27)
```

## Inclusion - feature showdown

To see, whats happening with script in some special cases, you can create an example `index.php`:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.php"/>
</head>
<body>

<script src="test.php"></script>
<img src="test.php"></img>

<?php require('test.php'); ?>
```

## Description

By parsing some standard-behavior headers sent from browser, we can predict loosely, what was context of page load. It's not 100% reliable and not a very good practice, but great for writing rootkits **;)** anyway.

Hopefully rest is commented-out in PHP code.

Tested with Apache serving and Chrome reading.